# MySQL multiple table UPDATE query using sqlalchemy core?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to update two tables using one query.

I'd like something along the lines of this

```
UPDATE tblReceipt, tblReturn
   SET tblReceipt.ReturnedDate = tblReturn.CreatedDate, 
       tblReturn.ReturnerName = tblReceipt.Name
 WHERE tblReturn.Id = tblReceipt.ReturnId
   AND tblReceipt.returned = TRUE
```

I currently have the following but I'm not sure how to add the second table reference. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
    update(Receipt)
    .values(ReturnedDate=Return.CreatedDate, ReturnName=Receipt.Name) 
    .where(Return.Id==Receipt.ReturnId) 
    .where(Receipt.Returned == True)
```

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Comment: my db is mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`update()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update):

> The keys within values can be either Column objects or their string
>   identifiers (specifically the “key” of the Column, normally but not
>   necessarily equivalent to its “name”). Normally, the Column objects
>   used here are expected to be part of the target Table that is the
>   table to be updated. **However when using MySQL, a multiple-table UPDATE
>   statement can refer to columns from any of the tables referred to in
>   the WHERE clause.**

Emphasis mine.

I've created an example core pattern based on your example above but not exact, although should be enough to work with:

```py
from sqlalchemy_app import engine

import sqlalchemy as sa

metadata = sa.MetaData()

receipt = sa.Table(
    "receipt",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("something", sa.Integer),
)

returns = sa.Table(
    "returns",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("receipt_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('receipt.id')),
    sa.Column("somethingelse", sa.Integer)
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    metadata.drop_all(engine)
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(
            receipt.insert(
                values=[{"id": 1, "something": 1}]
            )
        )
        conn.execute(
            returns.insert(
                values=[{"id": 1, "receipt_id": 1, "somethingelse": 99}]
            )
        )
        conn.execute(
            sa.update(receipt)
            .values({receipt.c.something: 3, returns.c.somethingelse: 4})
            .where(sa.and_(receipt.c.id == 1, returns.c.id == 1))
        )
```

As per the documentation, the parent table of the two columns that are referenced in `.values()` are referenced in the `.where()` clause.

Here is the update statement it generates:

```sql
2019-08-17 11:27:39,573 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE receipt, returns SET returns.somethingelse=%(returns_somethingelse)s, receipt.something=%(something)s WHERE receipt.id = %(id_1)s AND returns.id = %(id_2)s
2019-08-17 11:27:39,582 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'returns_somethingelse': 4, 'something': 3, 'id_1': 1, 'id_2': 1}
```

Note that if you just print the query out to inspect it, you'll get something that looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE receipt SET somethingelse=:returns_somethingelse, something=:something FROM returns WHERE receipt.id = :id_1 AND returns.id = :id_2
```

...as this is a mysql specific behavior you would have to compile it using the mysql dialect:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
print(statement.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect())
```

will print:

```sql
UPDATE receipt, returns SET returns.somethingelse=%s, receipt.something=%s WHERE receipt.id = %s AND returns.id = %s
```